# Naming of perchloric acid

Tags: acid-base

Why is *perchloric* acid called so? I am aware of the rules, but why is it not called *hyperchloric* acid? Or is it correct to also refer to *perchloric* acid as *hyperchloric* acid?

Comment: I would be more interested why it's even still called like that. IUPAC introduced newer nomenclature ages ago.

Comment: We have extra suffix for each of positive oxidation numbers in Czech, so we do not have such problems. Kyselina chlorná HClO, chloritá HClO2, chlorečná HClO3, chloristá HClO4.

Comment: In the mid 19th century, chemists apparently named it 'hyperchloric acid' with composition HClO7. But it was later renamed to 'perchloric acid' with a corrected composition $\ce{HClO4}$. So, in common nomenclature, acids with highest O.S is given the per- prefix. There is always IUPAC name to help you in case common name causes confusions. The compound  is actually $\ce{ClO3(OH)}$. So, the IUPAC name is " hydroxidotrioxidochlorine".

Comment: I doubt anybody would call it hydroxidotrioxidochlorine in nearby future.

Comment: @Poutnik. Indeed. That is quite a mouthful.

Comment: Thank you @NilayGhosh By any chance is there a peroxy acid of chlorine? If so, is it called perchloric acid?

Comment: Acids should contain the peroxo bond -O-O-H in order to call themselves the "peroxy acid". Unfortunately, there are no acids of chlorine which contains such bonds. So, there is no "peroxy acid" of chlorine. OTOH, there is a nitrogen oxyacid which is called "[peroxynitric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peroxynitric_acid)". Observe the bonds carefully.

Comment: Oh okay then. Thanks! Since there is no peroxy acid, there would be no confusion regarding perchloric acid and per[peroxy]chloric acid, which was what I wanted to ask about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This nomenclature comes from a long time ago. In the $19$th century, it was decided that the acidic compounds containing H, O and another atom X would be named from the name of this third atom X.

If only one molecule of such an acid was known, the name would be made by adding the ending *-ic*. Example: Only one acid is known with a Carbon atom, and it is $\ce{H2CO3}$, which is called carbon*ic* acid.

If two acids were known differing in the number of oxygen atoms, the most oxidized would follow the preceding rule. In the least oxidized, the ending would be changed into *-ous*. Example : In the $19$th century, the two following acids were known containing a nitrogen atom. Well  !$~\ce{HNO3}$ was called nitr*ic* acid and $\ce{HNO2}$ nitr*ous* acid.

If more than two acids were known differing in the number of oxygen atoms, the chemists would copy the case of the chlorine atom, where four acids were known : $\ce{HClO, HClO2, HClO3, HClO4}$. In this case, the two acids situated in the middle of the list are named according to the previous method : $\ce{HClO2}$ is chlorous acid, and $\ce{HClO3}$ is chloric acid. For the two extreme cases, it was decided to add prefixes, *hypo-* for the lowest number, and *per-* for the highest number. As a consequence, $\ce{HClO}$ became *hypo*chlor*ous* acid, and $\ce{HClO4}$ was called *per*chlor*ic* acid.

Today, the same regulations is applied, but the criterion of the number of oxygen atoms has been replaced by the oxidation number. The suffix *-ous* and *-ic* must be used if the corresponding acids have a difference of $+2$ in their oxidation numbers.

It should also be mentioned that the previous nomenclature is valid for acids having only one X atom. If an acid have two X atoms, the prefix *di-* should be added, and *tri-* for three X atoms. For example, $\ce{H2S2O5}$ is called *di*sulfur*ous* acid, and $\ce{H2Cr2O7}$ is *di*chrom*ic* acid. There are also other prefixes like *ortho-* and *meta-* to distinguish between acids having one X and the same oxidation number, but a difference in the number of H atoms.

Comment: In my understanding, the question was not about naming nomenclature the OP is reportedly familiar with. It was rather an etymology question why per- and not hyper-.

Comment: Maybe the use of the prefix "per-" is due to the influence of the French language. For example, in French the verb "forer" means "to make a hole in the ground". And if we add the prefix "per-", we get the verb "perforer" which means "to punch, to pierce, to make a hole so as to see the light through it".

Comment: Thanks for your answer Maurice but like @Poutnik mentioned, my question was why we refer to the acid as perchloric and not hyperchloric acid

Comment: @Metaxylene I guess the answer is similar as for peroxide, where there is also  superoxide, but not hyperoxide ( at least not in English, because CZ and DE do have hyperoxide ).

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite get what you meant. Could you please clarify? And why the confusion? Wouldn't just sticking to naming the acid hyperchloric acid at the time reduce confusion?

Comment: @Metaxylene Is there any confusion ? Naming conventions as for any other language say many "because" to many "whys". They do not always follow straight logic nor optimal way. Note that per- is not a convenience for hyper- but alternative prefix. Also, the pair hypo/hyper prefixes is used for low/high state of the same phenomena, what is not directly applicable here. There is no hypochlorate nor hyper/perchlorite.  And last but not least, per- is shorter and that counts.

Comment: Understood. Thank you. You've cleared any confusion I had about your previous post.